# Maven Artifact Search is always empty

Tags: intellij-idea, maven

When using Alt-Insert to insert a dependency into the POM, the Artifact Search is always completely blank regardless of what I search for.

I tried to add repo1  to Settings->Maven->Repository Services, it says "no repository found."  I find that hard to believe.

I've also tried to "update" my local repository but that results in an error.

FYI I'm using Community Edition Snapshot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used Artifactory to generate a `settings.xml` for me, and by default it pointed me to the "libs-releases" repository.

Instead want my "releases" repository to point to the much larger virtual repository "remote-repos."

All it took was a simple change to the options of the "Generate Settings" function.
[image: Need to change the "Releases" repository to a big one. We can use "Snapshots to point to our own builds"]

Answer (score 54):

If you have a brand new IntelliJ install and have never updated your Maven Repository, notice that there is a little "Update" button to the right that becomes clickable when you click on each repository.

> Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven >
>   Repositories

The important one is the https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ remote repository, make sure you update it.

Comment: View [this](http://i.imgur.com/VhZQkTj.png) image. Note that the update takes a long time

Answer (score 4):

Weird. The Artifact Search is working fine for me with IntelliJ Community Edition, at least for artifacts from the central repo that has been indexed:

[image]

And as you can see above, all repositories declared in POMs known by IntelliJ are listed.

There might be something wrong with your Maven settings. This is a wild guess but is your Maven home directory properly defined? Same for the user settings file? Is Maven actually working fine under IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1):

Solved - by reinstalling Intellij Idea

Search for class tab in Maven Artifact Search popup was always empty

Solution in linux:

1. remove idea folder (for me it was ~/idea-YOUR_VERSION_HERE)
2. remove ~/.IntelliJIdeaYOUR_VERSION_HERE folder  (settings)
3. download new version form jetbrains.com, unzip, run installer from bin

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a blocked port, as I am using my own artifactory repository.  Of course, the port it is using looks to be completely undocumented, but WireShark shows it to be 58754.  Sounds random, I hope it isn't!

Answer (score 0):

May be even caused by missing proxy settings. After setting a http proxy in IntelliJ idea, indexes were updated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).